# VSTS NuGet restore fails (proxy?)

Tags: proxy, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

Up to now we've been using Azure VM's for building our application. Because of legal requirements we were instructed to move these activities to an on-prem server which resides behind a proxy. Now I see the builds are failing with the following log message:

```
##[error]getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dist.nuget.org dist.nuget.org:443
```

So I am assuming this might be due to the nuget proxy config. So I've tried adding a nuget.config file with the correct proxy settings and checking that one in to the solution, but that didn't change anything. Also tried downloading the CLI and setting the nuget proxy config setting, but again to no avail.

The weird thing is; when I run the command locally from cmd, it all works fine!? So I must be missing something here, but what?

Comment: I'm sending this to our packaging team.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Brian!

Comment: Since it works from the cli (logged on as you), is the agent running as your account or network service?  Maybe try setting up another agent on the box SxS in another folder (download fresh one) and have it run as your account.  Queue a build demanding that agent.name.  See if that works

Comment: Running with the same account as I tried CLI with.

Comment: Could you post the detail build log here or share it on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT if you can let me know where to send the log I can share it. I cannot post the link here in public.

Comment: You can remove the sensitive information in the log, then share it on the OneDrive.

Comment: No sorry, I'm really not allowed to share anything over the public internet.

Answer (score 5):

@Jasper,
Hi, I'm Keith and I work on the packaging team at MSFT.

It looks like you may be using the [nuget tool installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/tool/nuget) to fetch nuget before running a build task.  Can you confirm that this is the case?  If this is your situation there is a known problem with the tool installer not respecting the proxy settings of the build agent that is being fixed.

Also, you should not need to set proxy settings in your nuget.config.  You should set them in the build agent via [this method](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#capabilities). The v2.* version of the nuget build task will discover the agent's proxy settings and use them when appropriate (e.g. restore).

Comment: Hi Keith, sorry for the late reply. The proxy settings we have configured correctly in the .proxy file. We are using the nuget tool installer indeed. Do you have any idea as to when we can expect the fix for that? It's beginning to become a blocking issue over here.

Comment: @Jasper - we're working on it right now.  We just added support to the tool lib (what the nuget tool installer uses).  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-tool-lib/pull/13

Comment: @bryanmac we just ran into this issue too / again (with agent v2.136.1) - This problem appears to be >= 1 Year old now.. is there any ETA when it'll be fixed?

Comment: @bitflipr Hi keith, will be this fixed? At this moment Nuget Installer Tool fails with proxy

Comment: Did any body found solution to this problem, as of 4/29/2019 , I am still facing this issue.